# How to inject or wire up ormlite into ServiceStack repositories?

Tags: repository, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, funq

I want to access the database from a repository rather than the service class (for increased seperation - not sure if this is overkill tho) i.e.

```
public class TodoRepository // : BaseRepository derive the class and inject IDbConnection somehow? 
{        
    public List<Todo> GetByIds(long[] ids)
    {
        return Db.Select<Todos>(t => Sql.In(t.id, ids));   <-- how to get 'Db' in here
    }
}
```

The service base class already enables direct access to databases via ormlite using 'Db' object thus:

```
public class Service : IService, IRequiresRequestContext, IServiceBase, IResolver, IDisposable
{
    public virtual IDbConnection Db { get; }
}
```

Leading me to believe I can do this perhaps so I can use 'Db' in derived classes:

```
public class BaseRepository: IDisposable
{
    public virtual IDbConnection Db { get; }
}
```

My AppHost has this line in it to pass in the connection string and register the repository:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
container.Register(new TodoRepository());
```

How to inject or autowire up the IDbConnection to the BaseRepository class?  I've already attempted registering and autowiring the BaseRepository in the AppHost with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the [Autowire registration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container) section in the IOC wiki docs.
This just registers a singleton instance, since you're passing in an existing instance the IOC is not able to control the creation of the type:

```
container.Register(new TodoRepository());
```

If you want it auto-wired, you need to use one of the auto-wired APIs:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<TodoRepository>();
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<TodoRepository,ITodoRepository>();
container.RegisterAs<TodoRepository,ITodoRepository>(); //shorter alias

container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(MyType));
container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(MyType),typeof(IMyType));
container.RegisterAutoWiredTypes(typeof(MyType),typeof(MyType2),typeof(MyType3));
```

Or you can manually control the creation of your instance by specifying a factory method:

```
container.Register(c => new TodoRepository { 
    DbFactory = c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>() 
});
```

If you want to inject an `IDbConnection` instead make sure it's in `Request` or `None` Scope:

```
container.Register<IDbConnection>(c => 
  c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection()
)
.ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```